# Java: How to get back to the main method after using other methods

Tags: java, methods

I'm fairly new to Java and the problem I am having is that this code compiles, but does not run after the hexadecimal conversion; it instead just ends after the method hexCharToDecimal. I can't reuse method main and I'm not sure how to call the method intreverse and actually have it run. Is there a way to get back into main or do I have to call intreverse somewhere?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Homework4 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        // Sum and average of a set of intergers entered by the user
        // First we will declare some variables
        int userInput = 1;
        int positives = 0;
        int negatives = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int numCount = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Will start a while loop that will stop when user enters 20 integers
        while ((numCount <= 20)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a nonzero integer or enter 0 to finish ");
            userInput = input.nextInt();
            if (userInput == 0) {
                break;
            } else if (userInput > 0) {
                positives += 1;
                numCount += 1;
                sum = sum + userInput;
            } else if (userInput < 0) {
                negatives += 1;
                numCount += 1;
                sum = sum + userInput;
            } else
                System.out.println("Error, please enter an integer");
            continue;
        }
        double average = (sum / numCount);
        System.out.println("The sum of the entered integers is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average of the enetered integers is " + average);
        System.out.println("There are " + positives + " positive integers and " + negatives + " negative integers");

        // Convert Hexadecimal number to decimal

        // Ask the user to input a string of 5 digits or less in hex
        System.out.println("Please enter a hexadecimal number of up to 5 characters");
        String hex = input.next();
        if (hex.length() <= 5) {
            System.out.println(hex + " in decimal value is equal to " + hexToDecimal(hex.toUpperCase()));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: please enter a hex number of 5 digits or less");
        }
    }
    // Now we will create the method to convert to decimal
    public static int hexToDecimal(String hex) {
        int decimal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
            char hexcharacter = hex.charAt(i);
            decimal = decimal * 16 + hexCharToDecimal(hexcharacter);
        }
        return decimal;
    }
    public static int hexCharToDecimal(char ch) {
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F') // check to see if there is any letters in the string
            return 10 + ch - 'A';
        else
            return ch - '0';
    }

    // Print entered integer in reverse
    public static void intreverse(String[]args) {
        // Ask user for an integer to be reversed
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer to be reversed");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        reverse(number); // Method to be called
    }
    // Will now state our method
    public static void reverse(int number) {
        // use a while loop to get each digit
        while (number > 0) {
            System.out.print(number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears to end there because that is where the main method ends. Any method called from main returns to main, but if the main method ends, that's it, there is no more code to call. If you want your code to repeat (you don't say), then use a loop, such as a for loop or a while loop.

Comment: I think you want all that code that is after the loop to be inside of it. If so, you need brackets `{ }` in the `else` near the `continue`.

Comment: just add a a while loop around your code in the main class.
`while(true) { //do something}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hex.length() <= 5) {
    System.out.println(hex + " in decimal value is equal to " + hexToDecimal(hex.toUpperCase()));
} else {
    System.out.println("Error: please enter a hex number of 5 digits or less");
}
```

Will always run once because it is not enclosed in any sort of loop. If you want it to run again when the second case is called then enclose it in a `while(true)` loop and have a break statement in the first case where you want it to stop execution.